# ZF and The Cardinality of The Set of Finite Subsets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In a comment on [one of my answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065799/every-in%EF%AC%81nite-abelian-group-has-at-least-one-element-of-in%EF%AC%81nite-order/1065804#1065804), I claimed that the abelian group generated by a set of $S$ generators, each of order two, could take on any infinite cardinality; this is equivalent to saying that, if we let $\mathscr P'(S)$ be the set of finite subsets of $S$ (with with the aforementioned group is equinumerous), then, for any infinite cardinality $A$, there is a set of the form $\mathscr P'(S)$ with cardinality $A$.

The axiom of choice clearly implies that this is true, because it implies that $A$ and $\mathscr P'(A)$ are equinumerous. (And that this holds for all $A$ is clearly equivalent to AC, since it implies that $A\times A$ and $A$ are also equinumerous). However, when we don't have the axiom of choice, is it still provable that, even if $\mathscr P'(A)$ and $A$ are not equinumerous, there still must exist some $S$ such that $\mathscr P'(S)$ and $A$ are equinumerous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that $\varphi:A\to\wp'(S)$ is a bijection. Let $A_0=\{a\in A:|\varphi(a)|\text{ is even}\}$, and let $A_1=A\setminus A_0$. Then $\{A_0,A_1\}$ is a partition of $A$ into infinite sets, and $A$ is therefore not [amorphous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set). However, there are models of $\mathsf{ZF+\neg AC}$ in which there are amorphous sets.

Comment: Why is $A_0$ infinite?

Comment: If $S$ is amorphous itself I'm not sure on how to count subsets... (it's a genuine question, not a criticism.)

Comment: @rewritten: I'm assuming that $A$ is infinite, so $S$ is infinite and has subsets of every finite cardinality.

Comment: Of course, I misinterpreted the $|\varphi(a)|$ as a count (of subsets), but it's just a size. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @rewritten: You're welcome.